# Line break is not working while trying to CONCAT two attributes of sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

i have made SQL SERVER Query . my requirement is concat TaskAction + comment and comment will have to come below each TaskAction . i have successfully done the CONCAT . but couldn't able to done the line break for comment text . please check my query

```
CASE WHEN WOTask.Comments IS NOT NULL THEN 
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),WOTask.TaskAction, 22) +  CHAR(13) + ' Comments:' + ISNULL(WOTask.Comments,'')  
  ELSE WOTask.TaskAction END AS 'TaskDesc'
```

and here is my output : 
[image]

as you can see in the screen shot Comment is in the same line . i want that comment part below the line. please help me with some solution . thanks in advance.

Comment: change the results to text instead of results to grid and you should see the `CR`.

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/19/sql-server-2005-ssms-viewsend-query-results-to-textgridfiles/

Answer (score 0):

You just don't see it in the output.  By the way, you can do this using:

```
(CASE WHEN WOTask.Comments IS NOT NULL 
      THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), WOTask.TaskAction, 22) + N'
 Comments:' + COALESCE(WOTask.Comments, '')  
      ELSE WOTask.TaskAction
 END) AS TaskDesc
```

That is, you don't have to put in special characters for the newline.  You can just have a string span multiple lines.